# Can you limit Google Maps timeline for alternate accounts on your android phone?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, accounts, google-location-history

I have multiple accounts on my Android phone, some shared with my kids.  I would like my location sharing to only be my primary account.  Is there any way to configure that?

One side effect, my son has his location shared with me.  But most often, when I look for his location, it shows where I am.